# How to make AzureRM not to drop previously configured properties of `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` at next deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

This is current configuration, `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<groupid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<sitename>/config/logs?api-version=2018-02-01` :

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<sitename>/config/logs",
  "name": "logs",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Website",
  },
  "properties": {
    "applicationLogs": {
      "fileSystem": {
        "level": "Off"
      },
      "azureTableStorage": {
        "level": "Off",
        "sasUrl": null
      },
      "azureBlobStorage": {
        "level": "Verbose",
        "sasUrl": "<here is fully specified sasUrl>",
        "retentionInDays": 0
      }
    },
    // ...
```

This is done in order to configure that `SasUrl` there which is done only after we have SA, and using Powershell. When `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` run with this template, those properties are lost (sasUrl and other).

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
  "name": "[variables('prodWebAppName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[variables('appServicePlanName')]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Website"
  },
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
    "hostNames": [
      // ...
    ],
    "enabledHostNames": [
      // ..
    ],
    "defaultHostName": "[concat(variables('prodWebAppName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6",
      "phpVersion": "Off",
      "alwaysOn": true, 
      "webSocketsEnabled":  true, 
      "appSettings": [
        // ... 
      ],
      "connectionStrings": [
        // ...
      ]
    }
  },
// .. and then slots configuration
```

That seems to happen because those `netFrameworkVersion` and like settings are under `Microsoft.Web/sites/<sitename>/config` also. Probably it should be put in a separate json template to run for this site or slot specifically. The template is used to provision all environments (AAT, QA, Prod) at once which makes things more complex.

Also, do you think it is right to make QA and AAT in App Service slots like MS advertise at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing? To my mind this does not suit well for script/template based continuous deployment/delivery for not simple systems.

Answer (score 0):

ARM is meant to apply final state to your resources so it will apply the values in your ARM template (blanks/nulls) to the settings in your resources.

Instead of using PS after the fact to create the storage resource and update the setting, have you considered deploying the storage account in the ARM template and [using a reference to it's key using listKeys instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit)?